# Do I need to perform a migration block when updating @PersistableEnum?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a realm model setup like this:

```
enum RealmEnumExample: String, Codable, PersistableEnum {
    case hot, cold, cloudy, rainy
}

final class RealmExample: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: Int
    @Persisted var weather: RealmEnumExample
    
    init(id: Int, weather: RealmEnumExample) {
        
        super.init()
        self.id = id
        self.weather = weather
    }
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

If I remove cold and cloudy from RealmNumExample and add warm do I need to perform a realm migration block in addition to updating the schema version? Realm documentation says that when adding and removing properties realm automatically does the migration for you but it is not clear with PersistableEnums in cases like these. When would renaming a property be relevant in this example? Lets say I "renamed" cloudy to warm wouldn't that be the same as removing cloudy and adding warm, therefore, not needing a migration block in that case as well and only needing to update the schema version?

I am confused on when it would be appropriate to resort to "renaming" properties in this scenario and doing a migration block or allowing realm to do the migration if it is handling it as adding and removing properties.

Comment: Great question! One thing to note: Realm objects require proper initialization through a [convenience init](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/quick-start/#import-realm). So, remove `init(id: Int,` and `override init()` and replace with `convenience init(id: Int, weather: RealmEnumExample) { self.init()`. Not doing it that way will prevent Realm from initializing the object and well, your code will go all wonky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, if the Realm PersistableEnum is changed in a destructive way, a migration will need to be performed to align the existing object properties with the removed Enum cases.

- Adding a `.warm` case only would be a non-destructive change and since no objects have `.warm` yet, there's nothing to migrate.

The reason is the RealmExample objects which have Enum values of cold and cloudy have the actual string value of `cold` and `cloudy` stored in the `weather` property (a string).

If those are removed from the Enum, the property values can no longer be mapped back the Enum to be resolved. e.g. cold no longer has meaning.

Updating the the version number along with a migration would be the solution. This code will map the objects that have a `.cold` case to the newly added `.warm` case.

You would insert any additional logic at that statement to determine which properties get mapped to the newly added `warm` case.

```
let vers = UInt64(4)
let config = Realm.Configuration( fileURL: pathToThisRealmFile, schemaVersion: vers, migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
     print("oldSchemaVersion: \(oldSchemaVersion)")
     if (oldSchemaVersion < vers) {
        print("  performing migration")
         migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: RealmExample.className(), { oldObject, newObject in
             if oldObject!["weather"] as? String == "cold" {
                 newObject!["weather"] = RealmEnumExample.warm
             }
         })
     }
 })
```

Comment: Thank you Jay! I have always been a lurker on this platform and your replies on other questions have really improved my learning and it so awesome to see you here on my first question. I was absolutely stumped, clearly. I really appreciate your code example as well. I also wasn't sure about how Realm handles the enum values but you clarified that they are type string. If I delete the cloudy property in addition to cold do I need to map the value to warm as well or can I simply delete it if I do not want anything to do with the cold value anymore? Not every old value needs to be mapped right?

Comment: The enum values are stored as strings because you've defined them as such `enum RealmEnumExample: String` they could also be Ints for example. If you delete the cloudy property, if any code or object references that property, it will crash as it then becomes undefined. So yes, if you remove enum cases and those cases are used in your other Realm objects, they need to be mapped to another value or handled in some way as the deleted case no longer exists. If the answer helped, be sure to accept it so it can help others. [How to accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)